# Using interval notation for sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is from Stitz et al's [Precalculus](http://www.stitz-zeager.com/szprecalculus07042013.pdf):

```
Example 1.1.1/2: Express the following set of numbers using interval notation:

{x|x!=3}
```

my solution: $(-\infty; 3)$ and $(3;\infty)$

authors' solution: $(-\infty; 3)$ *or* $(3;\infty)$

Why *or*? If $x$ can be any set of numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ except for $3$, then isn't it evident that it includes any positive *and* negative numbers on the number line other than $3$?

Comment: Do you mean $(-\infty;3) \cap (3;\infty)$ versus $(-\infty;3) \cup (3;\infty)$. The first one is the empty set since no number can be both greater than 3 and less than 3 simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, thank you for the notation. I understand that it is empty if applied to one number. But why can it not be applied to a list (or vector) of all numbers in R except for 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the formula : $\text {Set} =\{ x \mid \text {Form}(x) \}$ reads :

> $\text {Set}$ contains all and only those $x$ that satisfy $\text {Form}(x)$.

Now, the condition $x \ne 3$ is satisfied by **every** number except $3$.

If we want to write the set $\{ x \mid x \ne 3 \}$ in interval notation, we have to re-write the condition accordingly.

If we write it as :

> $x \in ((-\infty, 3) \text { and } (3, \infty))$,

this means that $x$ must belong to both intervals, and there is **no** numebr that belongs to both.

Thus, $x \ne 3$ iff :

> either $x \in (-\infty, 3)$ or $x \in (3, \infty)$.

Comment: Interesting. I guess the source of my confusion is that I do not understand where does it say that x must be one number rather than a list of numbers. Could it not be a list of numbers both higher and lower than 3?

Comment: @malasi - it is **not** a (single) number; the "solution set" is made of **all** those numbers $x$ satisfying the condition $x \ne 3$, i.e. exactly the two open intervals. Read my second line : the "solution set" contains all and only those numbers that ... (are different from $3$).

Comment: You are right. I found the formal definition in the book, which says the same as your second line: _The intersection of A and B: A ∩ B = {x | x ∈ A and x ∈ B}_. Thank you!